# How can I darken a rectangular part of an image in Java?

Tags: java, graphics

The code creates a JFrame with a JPanel onto which it draws an image loaded from a file. The objective is to make a rectangular area of the picture, such as for example the red square, appear darker than the rest. I'm assuming this may involve taking a subimage of the image, looping through an array of pixels, scaling them, and then painting that subimage onto the JPanel, but I don't know how to do this using the Java API.

```
package SpriteEditor_Tests;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImageTestApp extends JFrame
{
    public BufferedImage image;
    int x1 = 50;
    int x2 = 100;
    int y1 = 50;
    int y2 = 100;
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        new ImageTestApp();
    }

    public ImageTestApp()
    {
        setTitle("Image Test App");
        try
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/Paul/Desktop/derp.png"));
        }
        catch (IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("IO caught");    System.exit(0);
        }
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        add(new ImageDisplay());
    }

    class ImageDisplay extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawImage(image, -100, -100, getWidth(), getHeight(), Color.RED, null);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.drawRect(x1, y1, Math.abs(x2 - x1), Math.abs(y2 - y1));
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's been some time since I worked with Swing, but I think you can just place another JPanel over the area you want to darken, with a semi-transparent background color.

Comment: A [JLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) might be a decent way to do this

Answer (score 3):

A "simple" solution would be to just create a new instance of `Color` with the desired alpha applied to it and fill the area you want darkened.

This is great if you have a color you want to use, but when I want to use a predefined color, it's not as simple.  Instead, I prefer to use an `AlphaComposite` as it gives me some advantages.

[image: Simple]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/background.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (background == null) {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
            return new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

            int x = (getWidth() - 100) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - 100) / 2;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 200, 200);

            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
            g2d.fill(rect);

            g2d.dispose();
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(x, y, 200, 200);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Now, if want to generate a new image with the are darkened, you can follow the same basic concept, but instead of painting to the components `Graphics` context, you'd paint directly to the `BufferedImage`s `Graphics` content.  This is the wonderful power of the abstract nature of the `Graphics` API.

Don't forget, when you override a method, you are obliged to either over take ALL of its responsibilities or call its `super` implementation.

`paintComponent` does some basic, but important work and you should make sure to call `super.paintComponent` before you start performing your custom painting, this will just reduce any possibility of issues.

## Darken each pixel individually

Okay, if, instead, you want to darken each pixel in the rectangle individually, this becomes a "little" more complicated, but not hard.

After a lot of time and testing, I settled on using the follow algorithm to darken a given color.  This will push the color towards "black" the more you darken it, which some algorithms don't do.

```
public static Color darken(Color color, double fraction) {
    int red = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getRed() - 255 * fraction));
    int green = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getGreen() - 255 * fraction));
    int blue = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getBlue() - 255 * fraction));

    int alpha = color.getAlpha();

    return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);
}
```

Then, all you have to do is get the the color of the pixel, darken it and reapply.

For this example, I actually use a separate sub image, but you can do it directly to the parent image

```
BufferedImage subImage = background.getSubimage(x, y, 200, 200);
for (int row = 0; row < subImage.getHeight(); row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < subImage.getWidth(); col++) {
        int packedPixel = subImage.getRGB(col, row);
        Color color = new Color(packedPixel, true);
        color = darken(color, 0.5);
        subImage.setRGB(col, row, color.getRGB());
    }
}
```

Now, before someone jumps down my throat, no, this is not the most performant approach, but it gets over messing about with "packed" pixel values (because I can never remember how to unpack those :P) and most of my API code is based around the use of `Color` anyway

### Runnable example...

[image: Dark pixels]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static Color darken(Color color, double fraction) {

        int red = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getRed() - 255 * fraction));
        int green = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getGreen() - 255 * fraction));
        int blue = (int) Math.round(Math.max(0, color.getBlue() - 255 * fraction));

        int alpha = color.getAlpha();

        return new Color(red, green, blue, alpha);

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private BufferedImage darkended;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/background.jpg"));
                int x = (background.getWidth() - 100) / 2;
                int y = (background.getHeight() - 100) / 2;

                BufferedImage subImage = background.getSubimage(x, y, 200, 200);
                for (int row = 0; row < subImage.getHeight(); row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < subImage.getWidth(); col++) {
                        int packedPixel = subImage.getRGB(col, row);
                        Color color = new Color(packedPixel, true);
                        color = darken(color, 0.5);
                        subImage.setRGB(col, row, color.getRGB());
                    }
                }
                darkended = subImage;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (background == null) {
                return new Dimension(200, 200);
            }
            return new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (background == null) {
                return;
            }
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);

            int x = (getWidth() - 100) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - 100) / 2;

            g2d.drawImage(darkended, x, y, this);

            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.drawRect(x, y, 200, 200);

            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```